# R - converting a vector of 10 million JSON strings as fast as possible

Tags: json, r

Attaching a shortened example of my code below, to show what I am working with:
.

```
library(jsonlite)
my_JSONS

 [1] "{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":298536},\"12\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"1\"}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
 [2] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326300}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [3] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326295},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.88181118425883,\"y\":0.42416450778345},\"region\":2}},\"36\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"}}"                                                                                        
 [4] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [5] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
 [6] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326295},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [7] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326295},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
 [8] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326295},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.88526475286559,\"y\":0.52056553227969},\"region\":2}},\"37\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"},\"3\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null}}"                                             
 [9] "{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":116222}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[10] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575876},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.31542593275055,\"y\":0.58226218795729},\"region\":4}},\"36\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"},\"38\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"}}"                                           
[11] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[12] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.088641594240118,\"y\":0.6998714378427},\"region\":3}},\"37\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"},\"3\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"38\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"}}"
[13] "{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":298536}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[14] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326297},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.88986951100793,\"y\":0.56683802403789},\"region\":2}},\"37\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"},\"3\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null}}"                                             
[15] "{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":116222}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[16] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326297},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575884}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
[17] "{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":116222}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
[18] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1384076}}"                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
[19] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1384076},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.10015348959598,\"y\":0.58611822893714},\"region\":2}},\"36\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"}}"                                                                                        
[20] "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326299}}"     


> dput(my_JSONS)
c("{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":298536},\"12\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"1\"}}", 
"{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326300}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326295},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.88181118425883,\"y\":0.42416450778345},\"region\":2}},\"36\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"}}", 
"{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}", 
"{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326295},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}", 
"{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326295},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}", 
"{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326295},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.88526475286559,\"y\":0.52056553227969},\"region\":2}},\"37\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"},\"3\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null}}", 
"{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":116222}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575876},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.31542593275055,\"y\":0.58226218795729},\"region\":4}},\"36\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"},\"38\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"}}", 
"{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.088641594240118,\"y\":0.6998714378427},\"region\":3}},\"37\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"},\"3\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"38\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"}}", 
"{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":298536}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326297},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.88986951100793,\"y\":0.56683802403789},\"region\":2}},\"37\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"},\"3\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null}}", 
"{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":116222}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326297},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575884}}", 
"{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":116222}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1384076}}", 
"{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1384076},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.10015348959598,\"y\":0.58611822893714},\"region\":2}},\"36\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"}}", 
"{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326299}}")
```

.
In order to use the fromJSON function on this vector as fast as I can, I collapse the entire vector into one giant string, and then add brackets [] between each JSON:
.

```
my_JSONS_string = paste(my_JSONS, collapse = ", ")
my_JSONS_string = paste("[, my_JSONS_string, "]", sep = "")
```

.
and then finally I use the fromJSON

```
JSON_dataframe = fromJSON(my_JSONS_string)
JSON_dataframe

 8.type 8.value 12.type 12.value 1.type 1.value 2.type 2.value 26.type 26.value.coordinates.x 26.value.coordinates.y 26.value.region 36.type 36.value 37.type 37.value 3.type 3.value 38.type 38.value
1    Team  298536      NA        1   <NA>      NA   <NA>      NA      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
2    <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 2326300   <NA>      NA      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
3    <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 2326295 Player      NA      NA             0.88181118              0.4241645               2      NA  Unknown      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
4    <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 1575886   <NA>      NA      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
5    <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 1575886   <NA>      NA      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
6    <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 2326295 Player 1575886      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
7    <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 2326295 Player 1575886      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
8    <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 2326295 Player      NA      NA             0.88526475              0.5205655               2      NA     <NA>      NA  Unknown Player      NA      NA     <NA>
9    Team  116222      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA   <NA>      NA      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
10   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 1575876 Player      NA      NA             0.31542593              0.5822622               4      NA  Unknown      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA  Unknown
11   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 1575886   <NA>      NA      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
12   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 1575886 Player      NA      NA             0.08864159              0.6998714               3      NA     <NA>      NA  Unknown Player      NA      NA  Unknown
13   Team  298536      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA   <NA>      NA      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
14   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 2326297 Player      NA      NA             0.88986951              0.5668380               2      NA     <NA>      NA  Unknown Player      NA      NA     <NA>
15   Team  116222      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA   <NA>      NA      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
16   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 2326297 Player 1575884      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
17   Team  116222      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA   <NA>      NA      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
18   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 1384076   <NA>      NA      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
19   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 1384076 Player      NA      NA             0.10015349              0.5861182               2      NA  Unknown      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
20   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA> Player 2326299   <NA>      NA      NA                     NA                     NA              NA      NA     <NA>      NA     <NA>   <NA>      NA      NA     <NA>
```

.
and here we go. however, for a my_JSONS vector with 10M entries, running the fromJSON function ultimately takes quite a bit of time, in the range of 15-20 minutes, which is highly inconvenient for the code I am working with.

Appreciate any input / suggestions on this, including whether a different package or different structuring of the data will speed this up.

EDIT: additional info - i only need columns 1., 2., and 27. from JSON_dataframe, if that is worth mentioning. Thanks

Comment: `jsonlite::stream_in(textConnection(my_JSONS), pagesize=10000)`. No need to do the JSON array conversion. Tweak `pagesize` as needed, 10,000 seems optimal on my system when I do this for large files (which I do regularly). If they're in file, then replace `textCon…` with `file("filename")`

Comment: I tested this out with a vector of 200,000 JSONS, and my original fromJSON approach took 8.6 seconds whereas the stream_in function took 220 seconds... does this sound correct? 

alternatively, I'm still open to any other suggestions given this one seems slower

Comment: https://gitlab.com/hrbrmstr/ndjson - tested on Windows and OS X. Added some commentary to the original answer for it.

Answer (score 1):

Ugh. I did not expect this:

```
library(jsonlite)
library(microbenchmark)
library(purrr)

my_jsons <- c("{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":298536},\"12\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"1\"}}", 
              "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326300}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326295},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.88181118425883,\"y\":0.42416450778345},\"region\":2}},\"36\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"}}", 
              "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}", 
              "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326295},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}", 
              "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326295},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}", 
              "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326295},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.88526475286559,\"y\":0.52056553227969},\"region\":2}},\"37\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"},\"3\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null}}", 
              "{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":116222}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575876},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.31542593275055,\"y\":0.58226218795729},\"region\":4}},\"36\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"},\"38\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"}}", 
              "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575886},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.088641594240118,\"y\":0.6998714378427},\"region\":3}},\"37\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"},\"3\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"38\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"}}", 
              "{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":298536}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326297},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.88986951100793,\"y\":0.56683802403789},\"region\":2}},\"37\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"},\"3\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null}}", 
              "{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":116222}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326297},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1575884}}", 
              "{\"8\":{\"type\":\"Team\",\"value\":116222}}", "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1384076}}", 
              "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":1384076},\"2\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":null},\"26\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":{\"coordinates\":{\"x\":0.10015348959598,\"y\":0.58611822893714},\"region\":2}},\"36\":{\"type\":null,\"value\":\"Unknown\"}}", 
              "{\"1\":{\"type\":\"Player\",\"value\":2326299}}")

my_jsons <- rep(my_jsons, 1000)

length(my_jsons)
## [1] 20000

microbenchmark(
  stream_in={ stream_in(textConnection(my_jsons), pagesize=10000, verbose=FALSE) },
  purrr={ map_df(my_jsons, ~as.list(unlist(fromJSON(.)))) },
  string={ fromJSON(sprintf("[%s]", paste0(my_jsons, collapse=","))) },
  times=10
) -> mb

mb
## Unit: milliseconds
##       expr       min         lq       mean     median         uq        max neval cld
##  stream_in 3730.7919  3919.0835  3995.3708  3986.5055  4014.3850  4298.6312    10  b 
##      purrr 9700.8605 10019.6934 10191.8872 10095.6281 10396.6715 10808.0865    10   c
##     string  635.0473   753.4842   814.1994   851.3218   870.9981   932.7041    10 a
```

[image]

Perhaps slice your file into `n` parts and parallel ingest/convert them?

**UPDATE**

I threw together a test pkg based on a small pkg based on a C++11 JSON header-only library https://github.com/nlohmann/json and verified it generated the same data frame structure as the fastest string version you're using. I upped the # of JSON elements to 200,000 and did two trials with that pkg, one that used `dplyr::bind_rows()` and one that uses `data.table::rbindlist()`:

```
## Unit: seconds
##              expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
##      ndjson_dplyr 7.618801 7.618801 7.718406 7.718406 7.818010 7.818010     2   b
##  ndjson_datatable 2.547322 2.547322 2.852176 2.852176 3.157031 3.157031     2  a 
##            string 7.801338 7.801338 8.031613 8.031613 8.261888 8.261888     2   b
```

I can clean it up a bit and put it on github if you're interested.

Comment: thanks for the effort taking a look into this closer. yeah i thought the large string approach was clever, will look into parallelizing the code though. appreciate the suggestions.

Comment: I feel somewhat silly since I migrated from the "make the streaming json an array" approach to `stream_in()` w/o ever benchmarking it. There is quite a bit of "R" in `stream_in()` so I'm not too surprised by this, but the difference is definitely stark. I actually need to do this quite a bit so I'm continuing to work on a more optimal solution.

Comment: well then, glad I could help